# Access SNS from elastic beanstalk times out

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-sns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Are there additional networking permissions needed to reach SNS from an elastic beanstalk instance?

When deployed to AWS, my .net core application times out when trying to reach the SNS - for example, **list topics**.  This of course, "works on my machine" when running on a computer outside of the AWS network.

Example controller code:

```
[Route("api/sns")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class SNSTestController : ControllerBase
{
    readonly IAmazonSimpleNotificationService sns;

    public SNSTestController(IAmazonSimpleNotificationService sns)
    {
        this.sns = sns;
    }

    [HttpGet("list")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> List()
    {
        // *** TIMES OUT HERE
        var topics = await sns.ListTopicsAsync();
        return Ok(topics.Topics.Select(t => t.TopicArn).ToArray());
    }
}
```

The exception thrown indicates the SNS resource is blocked.

> Error: Connection id "0HLF7A2KOU7GP", Request id
>   "0HLF7A2KOU7GP:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
>   application. : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond --->

Answer (score 0):

Check the VPC of the Elastic Beanstalk instance.  If an SNS Interface endpoint exists, this may be causing the blockage.